# How many EC2 instances can be created for a single subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Condition is : VPC CIDR - 10.0.0.0/28 and Subnet CIDR - 10.0.0.0/28

So that we know /28 to /32 will be creating CIDR blocks of (0 to 15) 16 total.

But, when I tried in AWS to create an EC2 machine it created only 11 machines.

The EC2 machine's IPs are listed below:
10.0.0.4 to 10.0.0.14 (in series)

Ok! Think out of the box.

In the specified range, the last CIDR block IP will be all 1's so (255.255.255.255)

Why has AWS given an error even though there are still 4 CIDR blocks available also?

They are mentioned below:
10.0.0.0/32, 10.0.0.1/32, 10.0.0.2/32, 10.0.0.3/32

Please help in this case with why they are not used by AWS and replied with an error message of no IPs available.

Answer (score 4):

It's all in the docs:

> The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for your use, and they cannot be assigned to a resource, **such as an EC2 instance**. For example, in a subnet with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/24, the following five IP addresses are reserved:

```
10.0.0.0: Network address.

10.0.0.1: Reserved by AWS for the VPC router.

10.0.0.2: Reserved by AWS. The IP address of the DNS server is the base of the VPC network range plus two. For VPCs with multiple CIDR blocks, the IP address of the DNS server is located in the primary CIDR. We also reserve the base of each subnet range plus two for all CIDR blocks in the VPC. For more information, see Amazon DNS server.

10.0.0.3: Reserved by AWS for future use.

10.0.0.255: Network broadcast address. We do not support broadcast in a VPC, therefore we reserve this address.
```

More on subnet sizing in AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html).

Comment: Tqsm,  generally I think in whole network perspective so AWS differed a bit.